# link_to custom controller method with params

Tags: ruby-on-rails, link-to

I am trying to use a `link_to` to trigger a custom controller method. The custom method is used to trigger a mailer.

My `link_to` in the view:

```
<%= link_to 'Resend sign up instructions', send_sign_up_instructions_path(team: @team.name, email: email), class: "button tiny radius" %>
```

My route:

```
resources :teams

get 'teams/send_sign_up_instructions', to: 'teams#send_sign_up_instructions', as: :send_sign_up_instructions
```

Custom method in `TeamsController`:

```
def send_sign_up_instructions
  team_name = params[:team]
  email = params[:email]
  TeamMailer.notify_signup(team_name, email)
end
```

Error output:

```
{"email"=>"asdfasdfasdfasdf@adsfajsdfakjsdf.com", "team"=>"Some js team", "action"=>"show", "controller"=>"teams", "id"=>"send_sign_up_instructions"}
```

Am I missing something blindinly obvious?

Comment: Can you post complete error stack trace @Thomas Taylor

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems like there is a route pointing to `teams/:id` defined in `resources :teams`, so you cannot use `teams/something` as another route url. Just change it to some url else rather than 'teams/...'

This will work as an example:

```
get 'team/send_sign_up_instructions', to: 'teams#send_sign_up_instructions', as: :send_sign_up_instructions
```